# Adding utm parameters to hyperlink on a page.

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I am using google analytics to track traffic sources going towards my website.

I use several UTM parameters to track this. The one of interest is &utm_source=SOURCEHERE

These UTM parameters originally placed on the first link the visitor hits and are stored in a cookie so if a visitor navigates to several pages on the website the information is still available.

I want to make a hyperlink that contains that parameter.

a link example would be mydomain.com/folder?&source=SOURCEHERE

I have used this but was not successful:

```js
function getGATS(){
    var pairs = (/(?:^|; )__utmz=([^;]*)/.exec(document.cookie)||[]).slice(1).pop().split('.').slice(4).join('.').split('|');
    var vals = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
        var temp = pairs[i].split('=');
        vals[temp[0]] = temp[1];
    }
    return {
        'utm_source': (vals.utmgclid) ? "google" : vals.utmcsr,
        'utm_medium': (vals.utmgclid) ? "cpc" : vals.utmcmd,
        'utm_campaign': vals.utmccn,
        'utm_content': vals.utmcct,
        'utm_term': vals.utmctr
    };
}
document.getElementById("utm_source").value = getGATS;
```

Does anyone have any input?

Comment: The current version of GA does not store campaign information in cookies (it uses a single cookie to store a client id; attribution now happens on the Google servers) so unless you set the utmz cookie yourself this will not work.

Comment: What would be an option I can use? Can I set my own cookie?

Comment: according to https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cookie-usage

the source is stored in the cookie. The cookie name is __utmz

Comment: That was true for the old version of analytics (ga.js), which is deprecated since 2014 at least. The current version is Universal Analytics which does not use the utmz cookie.

Comment: thanks, what would be an alternative solution for this?